# Create HTML Table from nested PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need some help, I am trying to create a dynamic HTML table that will display some results from a nested array.

My array will always be setup like this:

```
Array
(
    [column_label] => Size No.
    [column_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => #3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => #3.5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => #4
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => #4.5
                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [column_label] => Approx. Diameter Inches
    [column_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 3/32"
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 7/64"
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 1/8"
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 9/64"
                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [column_label] => Approx. Diameter mm
    [column_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 2.38
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 2.78
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 3.18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 3.57
                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [column_label] => Catalog No.
    [column_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 32030
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 32035
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 32040
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [column_cell] => 32045
                )

        )

)
```

I need to go through each `[column_data]` array and prepare them to display as table cells in my table.

For example a row in my table should include table cells from the column_data array with a key of 0.  The next row in my table will include table cells from the column_data array with a key of 1 and so on.

Hope this makes sense, this way Im sure the cells will always correspond to Column_label table heading and be displayed vertically in cells.

Here is my failed attempt (unfinished):

```
<?php if ($product_table) { 
    //Setup empty arrays
    $products = array();
    $labels = array();
    $data = array();
    $column_cells = array();

    foreach($product_table as $product) { 
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($product);
        //echo '</pre>';
        //echo '<th>' . $product['column_label']  . '</th>';
        $products[] = $product;
        $labels[] = $product['column_label'];
        $data[] = $product['column_data'];

            foreach ($product['column_data'] as $column_data) {
                $column_cells[] = $column_data;
            }
        } 

?>  

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($labels as $label) {
            echo '<th>' . $label . '</th>';
        } ?>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
    <tr>
        <?php 
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($product);
            echo '</pre>';
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any control on how the initial array is setup? Just curious because having it organized by data columns rather than rows in an associated array makes it a little more complicated than it needs to be, and much more difficult to read.

Comment: Not really, if I print the products variable instead of product then each product is numbered, not sure if that helps.  In a nutshell I just the column_label to be the table heading and the info in column_data to be displayed vertically under the corresponding table heading.  I thought of using array_merge or using a for loop and counting.  Still not sure and have put way too much time into trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over your `column_data`, and using the array key, add the `column_cell` to the row based off it's key.

```
$labels = array();
$rows = array();

foreach($product_table as $product) { 

    $labels[] = $product['column_label'];

    foreach ($product['column_data'] as $key => $column_data) {
        $rows[$key][] = $column_data['column_cell'];
    }

} ?>
```

Then in you table, you need to loop over each row array, and print the cell data

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($labels as $label) {
            echo '<th>' . $label . '</th>';
        } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($row as $cell) {
            echo '<td>' . $cell . '</td>';
        } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

---

Using your sample data -

```
$product_table = array(
    array('column_label' => 'Size No.',
          'column_data' => array(
                0 => array('column_cell' => '#3'),
                1 => array('column_cell' => '#3.5'),
                2 => array('column_cell' => '#4'),
                3 => array('column_cell' => '#4.5')  )      
        ),
    array('column_label' => 'Approx. Diameter Inches',
          'column_data' => array(
                0 => array('column_cell' => '3/32"'),
                1 => array('column_cell' => '7/64"'),
                2 => array('column_cell' => '1/8"'),
                3 => array('column_cell' => '9/64"'))
        ),
    array('column_label' => 'Approx. Diameter mm',
          'column_data' => array(
                0 => array('column_cell' => '2.38'),
                1 => array('column_cell' => '2.78'),
                2 => array('column_cell' => '3.18'),
                3 => array('column_cell' => '3.57') )

        ),
    array('column_label' => 'Catalog No.',
          'column_data' => array(
                0 => array('column_cell' => '32030'),
                1 => array('column_cell' => '32035'),
                2 => array('column_cell' => '32040'),
                3 => array('column_cell' => '32045')  )

        )

);
```

You end up with this result 
[image]

Comment: You sir, are a saint.

Comment: always glad to help, happy coding to you.