# How do I create a HTML Table from this nested PHP array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

{
  "status": "1",
  "message": "OK",
  "result": [
    {
      "blockNumber": "9463854",
      "timeStamp": "1581452755",
      "hash": "0x70cc659946bc622ce17d66a67290423d50b32270cb7c6250e965956efa8b962d",
      "nonce": "24",
      "blockHash": "0xc60e1d62552e9e5839667e3c3929b8092dc1968601cb33c5470ee312167557a3",
      "transactionIndex": "9",
      "from": "0x3fc3f37bd729603cfbd7711156c8a9ee50e3578c",
      "to": "0x370740acd9369f32c837cbb7fc40bbb721c5d318",
      "value": "50000000000000000",
      "gas": "21000",
      "gasPrice": "13000000000",
      "isError": "0",
      "txreceipt_status": "1",
      "input": "0x",
      "contractAddress": "",
      "cumulativeGasUsed": "410433",
      "gasUsed": "21000",
      "confirmations": "116533"
    },
    {
      "blockNumber": "9463862",
      "timeStamp": "1581452893",
      "hash": "0x4059bae4387bbb422ce9a3c10b94e2945c052846139143e39ea2d4870ea2c696",
      "nonce": "0",
      "blockHash": "0x1e1258a9b35abe2010ff12f8f191f380a38729aa28d9ea77151685c5f4ff74e2",
      "transactionIndex": "21",
      "from": "0x370740acd9369f32c837cbb7fc40bbb721c5d318",
      "to": "0xbcf935d206ca32929e1b887a07ed240f0d8ccd22",
      "value": "30000000000000000",
      "gas": "279362",
      "gasPrice": "10000000000",
      "isError": "0",
      "txreceipt_status": "1",
      "input": "0x8853b53e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016eaa",
      "contractAddress": "",
      "cumulativeGasUsed": "1141363",
      "gasUsed": "214894",
      "confirmations": "116525"
    },
    {
      "blockNumber": "9499271",
      "timeStamp": "1581924331",
      "hash": "0x9670177bbef152974c5790f007896bc222516a64a9d2d3db8e012375f505d8d1",
      "nonce": "1",
      "blockHash": "0xb0c821fb0e94689912578ebcd2220f5ad919b17d588939af21d2bcf24ab1335b",
      "transactionIndex": "36",
      "from": "0x370740acd9369f32c837cbb7fc40bbb721c5d318",
      "to": "0xbcf935d206ca32929e1b887a07ed240f0d8ccd22",
      "value": "50000000000000000",
      "gas": "83361",
      "gasPrice": "4000000000",
      "isError": "0",
      "txreceipt_status": "1",
      "input": "0xf6838a720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
      "contractAddress": "",
      "cumulativeGasUsed": "1414997",
      "gasUsed": "64124",
      "confirmations": "81116"
    },
    {
      "blockNumber": "9571802",
      "timeStamp": "1582888995",
      "hash": "0xeb0c36285253d4e4e53f1c68ff0905dcd3e6300af7cd39a24cff44a41a5f8d6a",
      "nonce": "0",
      "blockHash": "0x1750e09bdd65d057f9b818f3554632850c359cee1a5cbb0ee3567fd728cf71be",
      "transactionIndex": "236",
      "from": "0x0389775569c6777ccbd157e62b8ca4a91aa0d885",
      "to": "0x370740acd9369f32c837cbb7fc40bbb721c5d318",
      "value": "67537140000000000",
      "gas": "21000",
      "gasPrice": "8000000000",
      "isError": "0",
      "txreceipt_status": "1",
      "input": "0x",
      "contractAddress": "",
      "cumulativeGasUsed": "8741378",
      "gasUsed": "21000",
      "confirmations": "8585"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, but the function returns the entire table row in a single line

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: function build_table($data){
    // start table
    $html = '<table>';
    // header row
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach($data["result"][0] as $key=>$value){
            $html .= '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '</th>';
        }
    $html .= '</tr>';

    // data rows
    foreach( $data as $key=>$value){
        $html .= '<tr>';
        foreach($value[0] as $key2=>$value2){
            $html .= '<td>' . $value2 . '</td>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
    // finish table and return it
    $html .= '</table>';
    return $html;
}
echo build_table($data);

Comment: the example from here did not work for me either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970612/create-html-table-from-nested-php-array

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Txn Hash</th>
<th>From</th>
<th>To</th>
    <th>Value (ETH)</th>
    <th>Value (USD)</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
<?php
foreach ($data['result'] as $key => $value) {  ?>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td> <?php echo $value['timeStamp']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $value['hash']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $value['from']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $value['to']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $value['value']; ?> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```